# having problrm running a flask

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am using a flask (app.py) to run the home.html, reister.html, login.html and a dashboard.html file and facing an error as it is redirecting to login page again and again.
i have used database methid and flask is also executing but while running after registering and doing login instead of dashboard it's moving to login page again and there are no erors in entering data in login page

here is the flask code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_secret_key'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<User {self.username}>'

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.form.get('username'):
            flash('Username is required!')
            return redirect(url_for('register'))
        if not request.form.get('password'):
            flash('Password is required!')
            return redirect(url_for('register'))
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        if User.query.filter_by(username=username).first():
            flash('Username already exists!')
            return redirect(url_for('register'))
        user = User(username=username, password=generate_password_hash(password))
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Registration successful!')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'username' not in request.form or 'password' not in request.form:
            flash('Username and password are required!')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if not user or not check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            flash('Invalid username or password!')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user)
        flash('Login successful!')
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        return redirect(next_page or url_for('dashboard'))
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    flash('Logout successful!')
    return redirect(url_for('home'))

@app.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def dashboard():
    return render_template('dashboard.html', user=current_user)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    login_manager.login_view = 'login'

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))

    app.run(debug=True)
```

and here are html files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
        }
        .container {
            max-width: 1200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .header {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .nav {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            padding: 10px;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .nav a {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .nav a:hover {
            color: #ccc;
        }
        .hero {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            padding: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .footer {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        @keyframes fadeIn {
            from {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            to {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Welcome to the Home Page</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Register</a>
            <a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</a>
        </div>
        <div class="hero">
            <h2>Welcome to Our Website</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>&copy; 2022 All Rights Reserved</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Register</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
        }
        .container {
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .header {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .form-group {
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
        .form-group label {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .form-group input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 3px;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .form-group input:focus {
            border-color: #6699cc;
            outline: none;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .form-group button {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 3px;
            cursor: pointer;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .form-group button:hover {
            background-color: #555;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .footer {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        @keyframes fadeIn {
            from {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            to {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Register</h1>
        </div>
        <form action="{{ url_for('register') }}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="confirm-password" name="confirm-password" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms" required>
                <label for="terms">I accept the terms and conditions.</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit">Register</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
        }
        .container {
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .header {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .form-group {
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
        .form-group label {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .form-group input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 3px;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .form-group input:focus {
            border-color: #6699cc;
            outline: none;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .form-group button {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 3px;
            cursor: pointer;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .form-group button:hover {
            background-color: #555;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .footer {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        @keyframes fadeIn {
            from {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            to {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>
        <form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username_or_email">Username or Email Address:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username_or_email" name="username_or_email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>&copy; 2022 All Rights Reserved</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
        }
        .container {
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .header {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .user-info {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .user-info p {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .form-group {
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .form-group button {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 3px;
            cursor: pointer;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .form-group button:hover {
            background-color: #555;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        .footer {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            animation: fadeIn 2s;
        }
        @keyframes fadeIn {
            from {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            to {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="user-info">
            <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}!</p>
            <p>Your email address is {{ user.email }}</p>
        </div>
        <form action="{{ url_for('logout') }}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit">Logout</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>&copy; 2022 All Rights Reserved</p>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the `login.html` page, the input field for the user name is named `username_or_email`. However, within the endpoint the form is queried for `username`. For this reason, the username is unknown and the login process fails.

Set the name attribute for the input field to `username` and your application will work as intended.

```html
<input type="text" id="username_or_email" name="username" required>
```

Comment: That is it, simply!